# How to make custom card in react native like bootstrap

Tags: react-native

I want to make a custom card in react native as we make using html and css with Top image and card-heading and card-text view

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this mate, there is a specific component:

https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/card.html

Answer (score 0):

Use native base cards component for that.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Content, Card, CardItem, Thumbnail, Text, Button, Icon, Left, Body, Right } from 'native-base';
export default class CardImageExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content>
          <Card>
            <CardItem>
              <Left>
                <Thumbnail source={{uri: 'Image URL'}} />
                <Body>
                  <Text>NativeBase</Text>
                  <Text note>GeekyAnts</Text>
                </Body>
              </Left>
            </CardItem>
            <CardItem cardBody>
              <Image source={{uri: 'Image URL'}} style={{height: 200, width: null, flex: 1}}/>
            </CardItem>
            <CardItem>
              <Left>
                <Button transparent>
                  <Icon active name="thumbs-up" />
                  <Text>12 Likes</Text>
                </Button>
              </Left>
              <Body>
                <Button transparent>
                  <Icon active name="chatbubbles" />
                  <Text>4 Comments</Text>
                </Button>
              </Body>
              <Right>
                <Text>11h ago</Text>
              </Right>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Ref link:- https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#card-image-headref